# Using cell value to reference another sheet

Tags: excel-2013

I am trying to use a cell reference to obtain data from the last row of a separate sheet.

I have the following datasets in my spreadsheet:

Columns B-G

Date - Order Ref - Net Value - VAT Value - Total   e.g.

24/1 - 607-WHS1 - £2500.00 - £500.00 - £3000.00

I would like to use the order ref as a value to jump to another sheet, which has the same name. At the moment I am using =('607-WHS1'!B###) to gain the Net, Gross and Total values and manually entering this reference each time, but I suspect there must be a way to do this with a formula.

I have tried =INDEX but only as =($C212&"INDEX(.....)), which may well be wrong.

Once the sheet reference works, I am also looking for a formula to find the bottom value in a column on the other sheet, and give me *that* figure as my Net Value etc.

Apologies if this isn't exactly clear and many thanks for any suggestions!

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDIRECT()` formula:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'607-WHS1'!B###"), ...)
```

You can even get the name of sheet from a cell like this:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!B###"), ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Taosique - just wondering if there's any way the forum will let me send you an example dataset so I can see what you mean? I haven't been able to make that work.

Comment: You could make a screenshot and post it in your post or upload it to imgur.com for example.

Comment: I am trying to use the bottom line of a sheet eg. the one on the right here, to fill in the data column on the index sheet. So (in this case) B, C and D 24 need to go to E, F and G 316. However, I'd like a formula that uses the reference in cell C316, then finds the bottom line of the relevant spreadsheet and uses the data from that line.

Comment: Please use this example instead. Much clearer.
https://www.flickr.com/photos/36491881@N02/16855458825/